# wrf-python import error for jupyter notebook python 3.8.5

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have installed wrf-python and all required dependencies which can be found here: https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html.

When I "pip list" it shows version 1.3.2 of wrf-python is installed. I am using Jupyter Notebook launched from the Anaconda Navigator.[Here is the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW6jd.png)

The error reads: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'.

I have read online that the asscalar attribute has been removed from the numpy library but I am confused why wrf needs this in the first place.

I have tried installing older versions of dependencies that have worked for people in the past but I have had no luck.